# Run Time error 13: Type Mismatch on code when I add certain lines of code

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, runtime-error

so my code was working fine until I tried to add a nested for loop and then I started getting a run time error 13. The line where the error is is surrounded by ***

This is my code before which was working:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim ColLtr As String
Dim Ave As Double
Dim STDev As Double

For i = 1 To DateTime_Column

ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, i).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
    Ave = Application.Average(Range(ColLtr & "1:" & ColLtr & LR)) ' Based on     all values
    STDev = Application.STDev(Range(ColLtr & "1:" & ColLtr & LR)) ' Based on     all values

Next i
```

And here is the code after which gets the error:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim ColLtr As String
Dim Ave As Double
Dim STDev As Double
Dim q As Integer
ReDim Range(LR1) As Variant

For i = 1 To DateTime_Column

Sheets(1).Select

ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, i).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
 ***Ave = Application.Average(Range(ColLtr & "2:" & ColLtr & LR))*** ' Based on all values

For q = 1 To LR1
Range(q) = WorksheetFunction.Abs(Cells(q + 1, ColLtr) - Cells(q, ColLtr))
Next q
```

Next i

My original thought was that LR was a long so I tried changing it to string data type but that didn't work either, maybe it has something to do with the for loop?

Comment: I don't see `LR` defined with an actual string anywhere in the code.

Comment: You need to add ave = Application.Average(Sheets(1).Range(ColLtr & "2:" & ColLtr & LR)), no sheet(1) gives the error!

Answer (score 2):

it's never a good idea to repurpose the name of something like a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) to something other than what it was intended to be. This is especially so in your case as you've decided to allow the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) to be the default [Range.Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) while redefining **Range**.

```
Dim LR As Long, LR1 As Long, q As Long
Dim Ave As Double, STDev As Double
ReDim vals(LR1) As Variant


With Sheets(1)
    For i = 1 To DateTime_Column
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
         Ave = Application.Average(.Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(LR, i))) ' Based on all values

        For q = 1 To LR1
            vals(q) = WorksheetFunction.Abs(.Cells(q + 1, i) - .Cells(q, i))
        Next q
    Next i
End With
```

I removed the whole `ColLtr` business and explicitly provided a [Range.Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) for all of the [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and 
[.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) objects.

You still need to do something with the `vals` array and make sure that `LR1` is properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

When running formulas or doing assignments from cells in VBA, most common reason for `Run Time error 13` is having Error Value in cells. Also as you are using  `Average`, if all the cells in the given range are blank you will get the same error.

Test like this:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Average(Range(ColLtr & "2:" & ColLtr & LR))) Then
    ave = Application.Average(Range(ColLtr & "2:" & ColLtr & LR))
Else
    MsgBox "Error value in cells"
End If
```

Comment: [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)(1, 6, *<range>*) will ignore errors but still needs at least one cell with a value.

Comment: There are always little caveats. That's what keeps the fun alive. and hence I used Most Common not always.

Comment: That seemed to work, but now I'm getting the same error in the code within the nested for loop.